# How many people are necessary and for how long to form an Ethnic Minority?

Tags: discrimination, languages

Everything is in the title.

For instance in Switzerland, the [Romansh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romansh_language) are considered an ethnic minority, even though only 36'000 people speaks the language (or I should say the languages since it is almost a different language in each valley it seems).

However, since the 1990s Yugoslav wars massive waves of refugees came to the country and kept their language and culture, despite a good portion of them now wearing Swiss passports. In 2000 there was approximately 103'000 Serbo-Croatian people, 95'000 Albanians, 90'000 Portuguese, etc., but all of those numbers probably doubled since. There is today as much Kurdish speakers than Romansh speakers in Switzerland (that is, 35 thousand people), which is interesting since those are both endangered languages/cultures.

All of them are much more numerous than the Romanshs, but they are not considered to form an ethnic or national minority at all.

If the reason for so is that they arrived in the country recently, at which point will be they considered to have been here for long enough so that they become a national minority ?

Comment: So you question is what is needed for a government to recognize a minority and by recognize you mean give them some sort of privilege (e.g. make their language an official one)? I'd guess that is dependent only on the relationship between the Gov and that minority, and not dependent on any objective criteria.

Comment: @user45891 No, I don't ask what is required for a goverment to give some sort of privileges, as this is a purely political question. I ask what is needed for them to be considered a minority *at all* by independent (non governemental) observers. For example the Kurds in Turkey are obviously a minority even if they aren't reconized. The serbo-croats, albanians, portugueese, etc... living in Switzerland aren't even *considered* to be an ethnic minority, they are considered either completely foreign or completely Swiss based on their passport, with no regard to their language or culture.

Comment: I tried to make it clearer with my last edit.

Answer (score 4):

That's not something that's defined in such a rigid way. Some people also object to the understanding of ethnicity as a set of discrete and mutually exclusive categories (think for example about the children of bilingual couples but also about societies where language, ethnicity and occupation were linked and people could “switch” as they changed their position in society).

You also have to consider who considers which group a minority. I certainly think Kurdish people can be considered a minority in Switzerland and perhaps some academics or activists describe them as such (I don't know any specific example in this particular case but I would not be surprised). As with many other complex social realities, you won't necessarily find a single agreed-upon definition.

On the other hand, when there are some specific (even if relatively “soft”) legal consequences, there is usually an effort to define minorities in such a way that it excludes recent migrations.

For example, the [European Charter for Regional or Minority Languages](http://conventions.coe.int/treaty/en/Treaties/Html/148.htm) starts with this:

> **Article 1 – Definitions**
>
> For the purposes of this Charter:
>
> "regional or minority languages" means languages that are:
>
> traditionally used within a given territory of a State by nationals of that State who form a group numerically smaller than the rest of the State's population; and
>
> different from the official language(s) of that State;
>
> it does not include either dialects of the official language(s) of the State or the languages of migrants;

So for this specific purpose, the Kurdish language was deliberately excluded but not on the basis of the number of speakers.

Comment: It is not clear by how many years and/or generations the *migrant* qualifier will apply. In your particular example, the kids of Kurdish people who are Kurdish natives but never set foot of Europa, are they migrants ? What about their grandchildren and so on ?

Comment: @Bregalad I almost added a note about that. To an extent, “traditionally” is a bit of a cop-out, of course everything came from somewhere at some point. So that's just as much about perception as anything else. Presumably it means something like before the 20th Century.

Comment: On the flip side, I am not sure it's useful to describe children who grew up in Switzerland as “Kurdish natives”. There are many distinct situations but the fact that beliefs/attitudes/practices change from one generation to the next is well documented. Typically, the language is not transmitted beyond the second or third generation.

Comment: Only time will tell whether those languages are still transmitted past the third generation. Before the 80s there was a culture of assimilation, migrants did everything to hide their foreign origin and certainly didn't speak their native language in public, certainly not to their kids. Nowadays it tends to be different and even in the case of interethnic marriages it's common that both parents transmits their own languages to their kids (sometimes resulting in trilingual kids if both parents are migrant, rare but I can name people in that case :) )

Comment: @Bregalad I don't think there is any strong evidence that this is the case, the idea that recent migrants would be somehow more difficult or less willing to assimilate is a common claim (especially among people who oppose it, harbour some specific hostility or aren't used to immigration in general) but people easily forget how contentious, say, early Italian immigration in France actually was. It takes time, that's all.

Comment: @Rekaxed I think you misunderstood me. I don't claim people are any more or less willing to assimilate than before. I'm saying it's become easier and more accepted for people to get a double identity where they both assimilate and keep their original language and traditions. That wasn't the case before as far I know, I have a lot of german and swiss german ancestors and it seems back then of them avoided to use german at home *at all*. Today nobody would act like that.

Comment: Back then people avoided to use non official languages, even in private, because this was seen as a potential source of troubles for kids. Today it's the opposite, multilingualism is strongly encouraged. Perhaps this evolution is specific to the area I'm lining in or to the people I've met.

Comment: @Bregalad I think you might be over interpreting anecdotal evidence. Many first-generation immigrants did use their language at home, even in the past, if only because that's the only one they speak well. That hasn't prevented assimilation at the time.

Comment: Well after all you should be right. If the migrant marries and gets kids with someone their ethnicity the language and traditions from the old country remains, but if he marries with an autochton or a migrant from another country, they'll not transmit their language in most cases. So I guess migrants will eventually form ethnic minorities if and only if there is a real will to keep their language and culture over many generations ?

Comment: Take a look at Chinatown in SF - that's a community that kept to their tradition (and well before 1980) even though they were actively being oppressed - so I don't think that assumption holds.

Comment: @user45891 For the most part, my guess would be that continuous arrivals of new immigrants make it what it is. SF Chinatown is not a group of 6th-generation Chinese that “keep to their traditions” as a separate minority. The real test is not whether there are some Chinese speakers in SF now but how many of these had ancestors in the US three or more generations ago. Of course, the picture is more complex in some cases but the phenomenon I describe is not an assumption, it's been well documented, even in the US.

Comment: Finally, Bregalad's point is that this is changing but Chinatowns are nothing new so if there is something special about them, it would already be well-known. Also note that oppression would often tend to prevent assimilation, not the other way around.

Comment: I meant Chinatown in the early 20th century when the Chinese Exclusion Act was enforced. And I agree with you that oppressed minorities would tend to keep toghether more, however Bregalad doesn't seem to agree: `Back then people avoided to use non official languages, even in private, because this was seen as a potential source of troubles for kids. Today it's the opposite, multilingualism is strongly encouraged.`